# `Cordova` - not able to install using `npm`

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install the `cordova` using `npm`. for that i am running a commond using the `admin` access as `npm install -g cordova` but it's processing some point and stopping at following screen shot:

No process later. i have given a hour to install but no-luck.

Node version : `v5.2.0` and the NPM version is : `3.5.3` even i have tried to clean the cache of the npm couple of times.

[image]

Comment: Do you have to configure the config of npm? You can try to set "npm config set https-Proxy" and "npm config set Proxy" maybe it is getting no Connection?

Comment: Yes, I did. no luck.